# Javascript - Simple Login Redirection

Tags: javascript, authentication, system

Been reading some JavaScript tutorials and attempted to make a simple login system. I used the following code for this purpose. The alert line properly executes but redirection line doesn't seem to produce any results.

**Question:** How can I make it work? What is wrong with the code?

**Note:** I am aware that this is not a secure login system. I just need it to properly redirect when different conditions are met.

I also tried different syntaxes for redirection line (removing quotes, parentheses, etc.). None of them seemed to work… in case this is just a syntax error.

**Code:**

```
<form name="loginForm" onsubmit="loginCheck()" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    <input type="text" name="passWord"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<script>
function loginCheck() {
    var usr=document.loginForm.userName.value;
    var psw=document.loginForm.passWord.value;
    var username="admin";
    var password="admin";
    if ((usr==username) && (psw=password)) {
        alert ("True Info");
        window.location.href ("http://www.google.com");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert ("False Info");
        window.location.href ("http://www.google.com");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: try window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems:

1. `href` is a string, not a function, so calling it as a function will throw an except and abort the script
2. You aren't returning `false` from the event handler, so the form will submit and override anything you were to do to `location`
3. You have an assignment where you are trying to perform a comparison

To fix this:

1. **Assign** a value to location: `location = "http://www.google.com/";`
2. Return from your event handler: `onsubmit="return loginCheck();"`
3. Be careful about where you use `=` and `==`.

---

Note that intrinsic event attributes were how we wrote JavaScript in the 90s. Coding practises have improved and we can now [separate concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) with [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

```js
function loginCheck(event) {
  var usr = this.elements.userName.value;
  var psw = this.elements.passWord.value;
  var username = "admin";
  var password = "admin";
  if ((usr == username) && (psw == password)) {
    alert("True Info - submitting form");
  } else {
    alert("False Info - going to Google");
    location = "http://www.google.com";
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', loginCheck);
```

```html
<form id="loginForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="userName">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="passWord">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

---

Also, please note, that trying to do authentication entirely client side is a fool's errand. It can be used for an example of basic event handling, but should never be tried in practise.

Comment: Learned quite a lot of information with your post (and links). Being too new to the subject, my phosphorus reserves are depleted. I will return to topic after some rest :) Many thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is **an** issue:

```
if ((usr==username) && (psw=password)) {
```

Notice the single = sign? This means you are assigning, and not comparing.

```
if ((usr==username) && (psw==password)) {
```

Change to the above and see if it works then.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't notice that one.

Comment: No problem. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I guess that would be notepad?

Comment: Haha ok, I only ask because if you use an IDE like Visual Studio or Netbeans, it should pick up on those mistakes and make your life easier :P

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

It is an object, not a function.

Comment: Thank you, sounds logical :)